# Why would a slot have 0% participation from sync committee (Sepolia)?

Tags: beacon-chain, sepolia, slots, sync-committee

I'm working on a service that listens to blocks from the Ethereum Beacon chain (both mainnet and Sepolia), and uses the `sync committee` for submitting proofs of transactions to a light client.

I encountered that slot `3506017` on the Sepolia chain has 0% participation from sync committee nodes ([link to Sepolia beacon chain explorer for this slot](https://sepolia.beaconcha.in/slot/3506017)). Naturally, this broke my service, since there's no sync committee used for this slot.

I was wondering what does that mean and why/when does it happen? Is it possible to happen on the mainnet as well, or it's an issue with Sepolia in particular?